# Should we do something about some lesser used and practially synonymous tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

There's a lot of very little used tags with no tag wiki that are used on practically identical questions. I think we should make a lot of them synonymous considering there's no reason i can see for having them around.

For example, [railways](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railways), and [trains](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains). [railways](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railways) only has 6 questions and [trains](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains) 10 and no tag description. Why are they separate?

The [aviation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation) tag has exactly 1 question and no description. Why not merge it with [aircraft](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft)?

[engines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engines) has 10 questions and no tag wiki with it seemingly being used interchangeably with [propulsion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propulsion).

Is there any reason why they're still separate ?

Answer (score 6):

If you see any tag which could benefit from improvements, including merging, synonym, wiki, please go ahead and propose it.

Tag creation is so easy that it's easier to make it wrong than right. I have seen users creating a [flat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flat) tag, because they didn't type the dash in flat-earth. And many more examples along that line, which I have tried to clean up.

Be my guest with taking the broom and the mop and help with cleaning!

Comment: Synonyms are *hard* to do using the system as a user needs a score of 5+ to propose it. Users who want to approve it also need a score of 5+ for the tag. Often a proposal on Meta is the better approach.

Answer (score 3):

I can't upvote @L.Dutch's answer enough, nor can I upvote @VLAZ's comment enough. We've all taken a shot at managing the tags and as important as it is, it gets tedious.

My recommendations (and THANK YOU for your willingness to take your turn with this!):

1. As written, this post has been answered. But if your goal was to also get the indicated tags merged, that's unlikely to happen due to the fact that it's not actually what you asked for (in your title).
2. The reason the synonym queue doesn't work is because, for reasons I can't explain, Stack Exchange never added that queue to the queue review system. Users need to actually look at the synonym queue to see if there's anything there or they need to open the wiki of one of the associated tags where it's indicated that it's in the synonym queue. It's not the queue itself that's a problem. Regrettably, it's actually easier to process the synonyms using that queue due to the underlying automation. C'est la Vie.
3. Consequently, it's often faster to post a specific question in Meta requesting the synonym associations. Such posts should focus on one synonym group per post.
4. OR, you can bypass all of this entirely. ***If you're absolutely confident that the tags should be merged*** you can edit the associated questions on Main to delete the tags that should go away and add the tag that should have been used. The result is that all the "bad tags" have zero associated questions. *Stack Exchange's automation will delete the tags in a week or two.* Obviously, when you're dealing with tags that have a lot of associated questions this would be an enormous amount of work — but, then again, if that's the case it's probably better that you seek community consensus anyway. Frankly, I see the purpose of the synonym queue, but as you've discovered, sometimes it's an enormous bureaucratic solution to a small problem.

Cheers, @OT-64SKOT. The help is *always* appreciated.